# Merging queries to return single response

Tags: mysql, nested, sum

I am writing a complicated website at the moment and I am a bit stuck. I am writing a query that returns the data for the categories of items. I need it to return an array for each category that includes the category name, id and description, along with the number of items that use that category and a value from each item under that category added up.

In other words, I want to return:

```
categoryid = 1
name = category name
description = category description
totalavailable = number of items in category
totaldownloads = downloads value from each item in category added together.
```

This is my query so far (it only returns the count and the sum, and they don't really work).

```
SELECT
  category, SUM(downloads) as totaldownloads, count(*) as totalavailable
FROM
  downloads
WHERE
   category IN(SELECT categoryid FROM categories)
```

And here is a picture of my schema:
[image: My database schema]

Please help me! I am stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your query is almost perfect, you just have to `JOIN` both tables to get all values:

```
SELECT
  c.categoryid,
  c.name,
  c.description,
  COUNT(*) AS totalavailable,
  SUM(d.downloads) AS totaldownloads
FROM
  categories c
INNER JOIN
  downloads d
ON
  c.categoryid = d.category
WHERE
  /* whatever */
GROUP BY
  c.categoryid,
  c.name,
  c.description
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly for my code. I love the quick responses here.